# The length of every linearly independent list of vectors is less than or equal to the length of every spanning list of vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am referring to Theorem 2.23 of the book is Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler. It mentions

> **Theorem:** In a finite-dimensional vector space, the length of every linearly independent list of vectors is less than or equal to the length of every spanning list of vectors.
>
> **Proof**
>
> Suppose $u_1, u_2,.....,u_m$ is linearly independent in V. Suppose also that
>   $w_1,w_2,...,w_n$ spans V. We need to prove that $m \leq n$. We do so through the
>   multi-step process described below; note that in each step we add one of the $u$’s and remove one of the $w$’s.
>
> **Step 1**
>
> Let B be the list $w_1,w_2,...,w_n$, which spans V. Thus adjoining any vector
>   in V to this list produces a linearly dependent list (because the newly
>   adjoined vector can be written as a linear combination of the other
>   vectors). In particular, the list
>   $u_1,w_1,...,w_n$ is linearly dependent. Thus by the Linear Dependence Lemma (2.21),
>   we can remove one of the $w$’s so that the new list B (of length $n$)
>   consisting of $u_1$ and the remaining $w$’s spans V.
>
> **Step j**
>
> The list B (of length $n$) from step $j-1$ spans V. Thus adjoining any
>   vector to this list produces a linearly dependent list. In particular, the
>   list of length $n+1$ obtained by adjoining $u_j$ to B, placing it just after
>   $u_1,u_2,...,u_{j-1}$, is linearly dependent. By the Linear Dependence Lemma
>   (2.21), one of the vectors in this list is in the span of the previous ones,
>   and because $u_1,u_2,...,u_j$ is linearly independent, this vector is one of
>   the $w$’s, not one of the $u$’s. We can remove that $w$ from B so that the
>   new list B (of length $n$) consisting of $u_1,u_2,...,u_j$ and the remaining $w$’s
>   spans V.

I have problem with the part that states

**By the Linear Dependence Lemma (2.21), one of the vectors in this list is in the span of the previous ones, and because $u_1,u_2,...,u_j$ is linearly independent, this vector is one of the $w$’s, not one of the $u$’s.**

Why does linear independence of the list $u_1,u_2,...,u_j$ imply that one
of $u$'s cannot be written as a linear combination of the rest of $u$'s and $w$'s in the list?

What I can understand is that if the author said **it must be possible to select one of $w$'s as otherwise, the $u$'s will end up being linearly dependent,** then he'd be right. If you cannot choose any of the $w$'s and the list is known to be linearly dependent, then one of the $u$'s will end up being in the span of the rest of the $u$'s. This is not what he states though. He states **it *has* to be one of $w$'s.** I think that statement is wrong.

If I am making a mistake in the way I have understood the proof, please help me understand it correctly.

Comment: The proof is pernickety about the order of the vectors: the $u_i$ are listed before the $w_j$ and the claim is that one of the vectors is linearly dependent on vectors that precede it in the list. I find the writing that you quote clumsy: even the statement of the theorem is badly expressed: what does "the length of every list such that *blah* is less than or equal to the length of every list such that *boo*" mean? If you have the option, try another book.

Comment: Thanks Rob for understanding me. While the proof is pernickety (and so is the content of most of that book), I like that book mostly because of its abstract nature. I don't like books where matrices and determinants are introduced too soon in the presentation. Do you have suggestions for such an introductory linear algebra textbook?

Comment: I believe [Cely's proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3732235/334795) is correct, and what I can get from the proof is that it is always possible to find one to be removed from $w$s, but it is not always for $u$s. That is, there could be a chance we can remove some $u$ and have a list that still spans $V$. So, I would say that he chose a safe way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> By the Linear Dependence Lemma (2.21), one of the vectors in this list is in the span of the **previous** ones

(emphasis added)

The author is not commenting on whether one of the $u$s can be written as a linear combination of the $w$s which *follow* it in the list. The Linear Dependence Lemma gives that one of the vectors in this list is the span of the ones preceding it in the list, i.e., one of the following things is true:

- $u_2$ is in the span of $\{u_1\}$
- $u_3$ is in the span of $\{u_1,u_2\}$
- ...
- $u_j$ is in the span of $\{u_1,\dots,u_{j-1}\}$
- $w_1$ is in the span of $\{u_1,\dots,u_j\}$
- $w_2$ is in the span of $\{u_1,\dots,u_j,w_1\}$
- ...

Since the $u$s are linearly independent, it is impossible for any $u$ to be in the span of previous vectors on the list. So it must be a $w$ which is in the span of previous vectors on the list.

Comment: Thanks Forman for the answer. I did not read the linear dependence lemma carefully. The proof now makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

At step j we have the list of n vectors
$$u_1,\ldots,u_j,w_1,\ldots,w_{n-j}$$
which span $V$. Then we add $u_{j+1}$ to the list and get
$$u_1,\ldots,u_{j+1},w_1,\ldots,w_{n-j}$$
Because $u_{j+1}$ is in the span of the previous vectors, this new list is linearly dependent (bullet point 2.20). So, there must be $n+1$ scalars $a_1,\ldots, a_{n+1}$ not all equal to $0$ such that
$$a_1 u_1 + \cdots + a_{j+1} u_{j+1} + a_{j+2} w_1 + \cdots + a_{n+1} w_{n-j} = 0$$
Now, to answer the question of why we can always choose one of the $w$'s as a linear combination of the rest, notice that if all of the scalars from $a_{j+2}$ to $a_{n-j}$ were equal to $0$, then all scalars from $a_1$ to $a_{j+1}$ should be $0$ as well, because all the $u$'s are linearly independent. But we said that not all $a$'s were equal to $0$.