# Proof of Rank–nullity theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm trying to understand the proof of [Rank–nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem),but there are parts that I don't understand:

**Steinitz exchange lemma**

> If ${\displaystyle U=\{u_{1},\dots ,u_{m}\}}$ is a set of ${\displaystyle m}$ linearly independent vectors in a vector space ${\displaystyle V}$, and ${\displaystyle W=\{w_{1},\dots ,w_{n}\}}$ span ${\displaystyle V}$, then:

> 1. ${\displaystyle m\leq n}$;

> 2. There is a set ${\displaystyle W'\subseteq W}$ with ${\displaystyle |W'|=n-m}$ such that ${\displaystyle U\cup W'}$ spans ${\displaystyle V}$.

**Rank–nullity theorem**

> Let ${\displaystyle V}, {\displaystyle W}$ be vector spaces, where ${\displaystyle V}$ is finite dimensional. Let ${\displaystyle T\colon V\to W}$ be a linear transformation. Then

> $${\displaystyle \operatorname {Rank} (T)+\operatorname {Nullity} (T)=\dim V}$$

**Proof**

> Let ${\displaystyle V,W}$ be vector spaces over some field ${\displaystyle \mathbb {F} }$  and ${\displaystyle T}$ defined as in the statement of the theorem with ${\displaystyle \dim V=n}$.

> As ${\displaystyle \operatorname {Ker} T\subset V}$ is a subspace, there exists a basis for it. Suppose ${\displaystyle \dim \operatorname {Ker} T=k}$

I know that $\text{ker T}$ is a subset of a finite set $V$,and hence is finite,but how does this imply that $\text{ker T}$ does have a basis?

> and let ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {K}}:=\{v_{1},\ldots ,v_{k}\}\subset \operatorname {Ker} (T)}$
> be such a basis.

> We may now, by the Steinitz exchange lemma, extend ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {K}}}$ with ${\displaystyle n-k}$ linearly independent vectors ${\displaystyle w_{1},\ldots ,w_{n-k}}$ to form a full basis of ${\displaystyle V}$.

> Let

> ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {S}}:=\{w_{1},\ldots ,w_{n-k}\}\subset V\setminus \operatorname {Ker} (T)}$
> such that

> ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {B}}:={\mathcal {K}}\cup {\mathcal {S}}=\{v_{1},\ldots ,v_{k},w_{1},\ldots ,w_{n-k}\}\subset V}$
> is a basis for ${\displaystyle V}$.

What is $V,W,W',U$ here? Since the proof uses Steinitz exchange lemma,however I can't recognize  $V,W,W',U$.

> From this, we know that ${\displaystyle \operatorname {Im} T=\operatorname {Span} T({\mathcal {B}})=\operatorname {Span} \{T(v_{1}),\ldots ,T(v_{k}),T(w_{1}),\ldots ,T(w_{n-k})\}=\operatorname {Span} \{T(w_{1}),\ldots ,T(w_{n-k})\}=\operatorname {Span} T({\mathcal {S}})}$

Why $\text{Im}\; T=\text{span} \;T (\mathcal B)$?

And why  $\operatorname {Span} \{T(v_{1}),\ldots ,T(v_{k}),T(w_{1}),\ldots ,T(w_{n-k})\}=\operatorname {Span} \{T(w_{1}),\ldots ,T(w_{n-k})\}$?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Every finite-dimensional space has a basis. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2785769/proof-of-every-finite-dimensional-vector-space-has-a-finite-basis

Comment: Second question: $V,W$ were given as your vector spaces, $W'$ is the $n-k$ linearly independent vectors $w_1,\dots,w_{n-k}$, $U$ is $\mathcal K$. Third question: Im $T$ is Span$T(\mathcal B)$ by definition; the image of a linear map is all vectors spanned by a basis of its image. Fourth question: it is because $v_1,\dots,v_k$ are in the kernel, so they don't "change" the span.

Answer (score 1):

1. $\ker T$ is a subspace, hence it is a vector space, so it has a basis.
2. $V$ is $V$, $W$ is any fixed basis of $V$, $U=\mathcal K$ and $W'=\mathcal S$.
3. It's because $\mathcal B$ is a basis of $V$, thus in particular every vector is a linear combination of them, and $T$ is linear.
4. $T(v_i)=0$ since $v_i\in\ker T$.

Comment: It's by construction: first let $W$ be an arbitrary basis of $V$, then consider an arbitrary basis $U$ of $\ker T$. $U$ remains linearly independent in $V$. Apply Steinitz exchange lemma *to obtain* $W'\subseteq W$ with the given property.

Answer (score 0):

let $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ be a basis for $V$ then for all $v \in V$

$v=c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n$ $\Rightarrow$  $T(v)=T(C_1v_1+...+c_nv_n)=c_1T(v_1)+...+c_nT(v_n) \in \text{span} \;T (\mathcal B)$

similarly, $w \in \text{span} \;T (\mathcal B) \Rightarrow w=T(c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n) \in 
Im(T)$

that is why $Im(T)=\text{span} \;T (\mathcal B)$

Comment: yes these are the hidden  steps that were not written in my proof