# Let $G$ be abelian s.t. $r_p(G)<\infty$ if $p=0$ or prime. If $H\le G$, show $r_p(G/H)\le r_0(G)+r_p(G)$ for $p>0$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, quotient-group

This is **Exercise 4.3.9(a)** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3Aquotient%2C%20OR%20content%3Aabelian%2C%20OR%20content%3Arank&p=10), it is new to MSE.

It is an exercise noted as being referred to later on in the text.

### The Details:

On page 98 to 99, *ibid.*, we have

> Let $G$ be an abelian group and let $S$ be a nonempty subset of $G$. Then  $S$ is called *linearly independent*, or simply *independent*, if $0\notin S$ and, given distinct elements $s_1,\dots, s_r$ of $S$ and integers $m_1,\dots, m_r$, the relation $m_1s_1+\dots+m_rs_r=0$ implies $m_is_i=0$ for all $i$.

. . . and . . .

> If $p$ is prime and $G$ is an abelian group, the *$p$-rank* of $G$
>
> $$r_p(G)$$
>
> is defined as the cardinality of a maximal independent subset of elements of $p$-power order. Similarly the *$0$-rank* or *torsion-free rank*
>
> $$r_0(G)$$
>
> is the cardinality of a maximal independent subset of elements of infinite order.

### The Question:

> Let $G$ be an abelian such that $r_p(G)<\infty$ if $p=0$ or a prime.
>
> (a) If $H\le G$, show that $r_p(G/H)\le r_0(G)+r_p(G)$ for all $p>0$.

### Thoughts:

I have asked questions here on related concepts:

- [For $H\le G$, abelian $G$, show that $r_0(H)+r_0(G/H)=r_0(G)$, where $r_0(K)$ is the torsionfree rank of $K$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4205100/104041)
- [If $H\le G$ for an abelian group $G$, then $r_p(H)+r_p(G/H)\ge r_p(G)$, where $r_p(K)$ is the $p$-rank of $K$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4212211/104041)

---

I'm completely stuck.

However, to be honest, I haven't given it much time: I'm approaching the end of my postgraduate research degree so I've been too busy. I'm asking so that I can maintain a good pace in the book without forgetting the preceding material.

The kind of answer I'm looking for is a full solution, please.

The exercise is in the section on pure subgroups and $p$-groups. This suggests that I could use these concepts. I don't see the connection. There is the following theorem on page 110:

> **4.3.13.** An abelian $p$-group $G$ has finite $p$-rank if and only if it is a direct sum of finitely many cyclic and quasicyclic groups.

That's the only direct mention of $p$-rank in the section.

---

I know, since $G$ is abelian, that $H$ is normal and $G/H$ is abelian.

---

I hope this is enough context.

Please help :)

Comment: Haven't thought this through, but my first impulse would be the following: if you take a maximal independent $p$-subset of $G/H$, and lift it, some of the elements will have finite order, some will have infinite order; that's why you get the $r_0$ and the $r_p$ in the inequality. So try to construct an independent set of elements in $G$; the torsion ones will have order a multiple of a power of $p$ so you can replace them with a multiple to get order power of $p$. As I said, just a very rough idea of what I might try as a first approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two things you need to realize is that

1. The image of a linearly dependent set is linearly dependent, and
2. If $\{x_1^{a_1},\dots,x_n^{a_n}\}$ is a linearly dependent then so is $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$.

It's the contrapositives of these that you need, but this way round is much more obvious for some reason!

Suppose that $r_p(G/H)=n$ (including the possibility that $n=\infty$), and let $Hx_1,\dots,Hx_n$ be a linearly independent set of $p$-elements of $G/H$. (OK, if $n=\infty$, replace it by some incredibly large finite number.) Taking preimages yields a linearly independent set of $G$ (by 1.) Some of these are of infinite order and some of finite order. Let $x_1,\dots,x_m$ be infinite order and $y_1,\dots,y_r$ be finite order. Since $Hy_i$ is a non-trivial $p$-element, $o(y_i)$ is divisible by $p$. Thus some power of $y_i$ is a non-trivial $p$-element, $y_i'$. The $y_i'$ are linearly independent by 2. Thus $m\leq r_0(G)$ and $r\leq r_p(G)$, as needed for the equation
$$ r_p(G/H)=n=m+r\leq r_0(G)+r_p(G).$$

Comment: Thank you. How come $Hy_i$ is a $p$-element?

Comment: Good point. I forgot to assume that. Since we are considering $r_p(G/H)$ the $Hy_i$ should be $p$-elements.