# Let $G$ be abelian s.t. $r_p(G)<\infty$ if $p=0$ or a prime. Prove $G/nG$ is finite for all $n>0$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, quotient-group

This is **Exercise 4.3.9(b)** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3AFinite%2C%20OR%20content%3Aabelian%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24G%2FnG%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24n%3E0%24&p=10), it is new to MSE.

This question is referred to later on in the text.

The previous part is here:

- [Let $G$ be abelian s.t. $r_p(G)<\infty$ if $p=0$ or prime. If $H\le G$, show $r_p(G/H)\le r_0(G)+r_p(G)$ for $p>0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4253779/104041)

Questions of mine on similar topics include:

- [For $H\le G$, abelian $G$, show that $r_0(H)+r_0(G/H)=r_0(G)$, where $r_0(K)$ is the torsionfree rank of $K$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4205100/104041)
- [If $H\le G$ for an abelian group $G$, then $r_p(H)+r_p(G/H)\ge r_p(G)$, where $r_p(K)$ is the $p$-rank of $K$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4212211/104041)

### The Details:

On page 98 to 99, *ibid.*, we have

> Let $G$ be an abelian group and let $S$ be a nonempty subset of $G$. Then  $S$ is called *linearly independent*, or simply *independent*, if $0\notin S$ and, given distinct elements $s_1,\dots, s_r$ of $S$ and integers $m_1,\dots, m_r$, the relation $m_1s_1+\dots+m_rs_r=0$ implies $m_is_i=0$ for all $i$.

. . . and . . .

> If $p$ is prime and $G$ is an abelian group, the *$p$-rank* of $G$
>
> $$r_p(G)$$
>
> is defined as the cardinality of a maximal independent subset of elements of $p$-power order. Similarly the *$0$-rank* or *torsion-free rank*
>
> $$r_0(G)$$
>
> is the cardinality of a maximal independent subset of elements of infinite order.

Note that

$$nG=\{ng\mid g\in G\}$$

is the set of all $n$th multiples of elements of an abelian group $G$.

### The Question:

> Let $G$ be an abelian group such that $r_p(G)<\infty$ if $p=0$ or a prime.
>
> (b) Prove that $G/nG$ is finite for all $n>0$.

### Thoughts:

Let $G$ be as defined above.

The Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups is not discussed in Robinson's book yet. However, I get the impression that the case when $G$ is finitely generated is much easier.

---

Since $G$ is abelian, $nG\unlhd G$, so the question makes sense.

*Proof:* We have $e=ne\in nG$, so $nG\neq \varnothing$. All multiples of any element of $G$ are in $G$ by closure of $G$, so $nG\subseteq G$. Let $x,y\in nG$. Then there exist $g,h\in G$ such that $x=ng, y=nh$. Thus

$$\begin{align}
x-y&=ng-(nh)\\
&=n(g-h),
\end{align}$$

for $g-h\in G$, so $x-y\in nG$. Hence $nG\le G$ by the one-step subgroup test. Moreover, for $k\in G$, we have $k+x-k=x\in nG$, so $nG\unlhd G$.$\square$

Indeed, all subgroups of an abelian group are normal in that group.

---

If $G$ is finite, then so is $G/nG$, since

$$\lvert G\rvert=\lvert G/nG\rvert\lvert nG\rvert.$$

This is rather easy to see.

---

I'm not sure how to incorporate the $p$-rank and $0$-rank of $G$ nor of $G/nG$, only each of $G/nG$ is at most that of $G$, and it is necessary to have/show that $r_0(G/nG)=0$.

---

The question is easy if $G=\Bbb Z$.

---

The kind of answer I'm hoping for is a full solution, please.

I think I could answer this myself if I had more time. As with the previous part of this question, though, I am trying to maintain a reasonable pace in the book, and after a week, I think it's ripe for asking here.

Please help :)

Comment: $G/nG$ has exponent dividing $n$, so write as a product of Sylow $p$-subgroups for $p\mid n$. There are finitely many such Sylows, so if all are finite then $|G/nG|$ is finite. But they must all be finite because they have exponent at most $n$ and rank at most $r_0(G)+r_p(G)$ by the previous part.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidA.Craven. I'm afraid Robinson doesn't cover Sylow's theorem for infinite groups until much, much later in the book. I cannot use your observation.

Comment: Replace Sylows by 4.3.5 from the book then. Same outcome.

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. Thank you, @DavidA.Craven. I invite you to write an answer below, please.

Comment: For completeness: "**Theorem 4.3.5:** (Prüfer, Baer). An abelian group $G$ is bounded if and only if it is a direct sum of cyclic groups with boundedly finite orders."